# PHP: Strange effect when passing array into MongoCollection#insert()

Tags: php, mongodb

In PHP arrays are assigned by value. Hence, when I do something like this:

```
$a = ['a' => 'ape'];
$b = $a;

$a['b'] = 'banana';
```

Only $a will have the key 'b', but $b won't be modified. That also applies when either array is assigned by reference into a function and that function modifies the array.

However, there's a strange thing happening if I try to insert a document using the PECL MongoDB extension. In the following unit test the second assertion fails for me:

```
public function testUpdateGeneratesId()
{
  $doc1 = ['author' => 'j.henning', 'title' => 'My Blog Entry'];
  $doc2 = $doc1;

  $this->blog->insert($doc1, ['w' => 1]);

  $this->assertNotNull($doc1['_id']);
  $this->assertArrayNotHasKey('_id', $doc2);
}
```

The #insert() generates the key '_id' on the inserted document, but I would expect the key only to be added to $doc1. However, it's created on both arrays.

Can anybody reproduce this behavior or give any explanation for it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug related to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-410 - can you please file a new bug at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP for this?